# Deep linking on a new window using file:// with aot

Tags: angular, electron

#### Context

I'm creating a desktop version of an angular app, for that I'm using electron.

Opening main window is quite easy:

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    icon: `file://${__dirname}/dist/assets/logo.png`
});

win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/index.html`);
```

This opens a new window, resolving to the base href path, everything works fine.

In my application, I want to make use of electron to provide things such as overlay windows to display informations to the users in a very compact way.

To make this, I have a page that can be rendered as overlay (`/alarms?overlay=true`) thanks to router's queryParams bindings.

Everything mentionned above works perfectly using a browser, the overlay is okay, everything is fine.

#### Problem

To open this overlay on electron, I'm providing a button that makes an ipc call:

```
showOverlay(): void {
    this.ipc.send('overlay', '/alarms');
}
```

Here is the send method from IpcService (named ipc in the function above):

```
public send(channel: string, ...args: any[]): void {
    if (this._ipc !== undefined) {
        return this._ipc.send(channel, ...args);
    }
}
```

And the code on the other side:

```
ipcMain.on('overlay', (event, url) => {
    const overlayWindowConfig = {
        height: 400,
        width: 280,
        resizable: true,
        frame: false,
        alwaysOnTop: true,
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false
        }
    };
    const overlay = new BrowserWindow(overlayWindowConfig);
    overlay.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/index.html#${url}?overlay=true`);
    openedOverlays[url] = overlay;
});
```

As you can see, i'm trying to open a new window directly on a given page, so it can load just the overlay without having to load home page and then navigate to alarms (which would be ugly due to the size of the overlay window).

#### Configuration

- Router base href is set to `./`.
- Router location strategy is set to `useHash: true` in the electron version, because that's how I'm supposed to be able to handle deep linking with `file://`.

#### Already tried

**Base Href**

Setting base href to empty ("") as I saw on a [github issue](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron/issues/58) that it should work using that.
 * Turns out this works perfectly without aot, building the app with aot breaks the window when it opens with the following message (inside electron's devTools):

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'index.html'

This also breaks all my assets links, as they try to load from `dist/index.html/assets/` instead of `dist/assets/`.

**Link modification**

I tried to change the link opened by adding a slash before the `#`, didn't change anything.

For now, I'm building my electron app without aot but this is not a solution that I want to use for my release, being able to load frame from electron with a deep link and aot enabled is a thing I need to be able to do.

Comment: Have you ejected the webpack and added to build for electron-renderer? Why do you use `file://`? I think relative paths are enough.

Comment: @androbin I would like to avoid ejecting webpack, as I like following angular defaults, so they are updated with angular cli tool and I don't have to manage them by myself. I'm using file:// because it's in an electron app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly where is the problem, but i think you could try implementing `UrlSerializer` compatible with `file:///` protocol and file names or atleast check `DefaultUrlSerializer` implementation.

Comment: I didn't even know about UrlSerializer, thanks for the tip, i'll check this possibility and accept the answer if it's the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Even if there's maybe a better way to solve the issue, UrlSerializer seems to be the way to go, didn't have time to dive into that recently but from what I've seen, it's the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use file:// links. I know it is an electron project, but webpack builder will not find the files.

You should eject the webpack, and change it to build with `electron-renderer` option. Look at any of the electron-angular-starter repo. It has to be done.

You can send a feature request to the angular-cli to implement this feature without ejecting.

Comment: So I should use http:// instead? But then, I would have to start an express server to serve the files, and I feel like it's not the way to go, as I could also just fetch main website and play with it.

Comment: You should use no scheme. Put the files in a directory that webpack builds (e.g. `src/assets`) and reference files from there as `/assets/example.jpg`.